# SQL resultado de un select en otro select

Tags: sql

6. Listar **numero**, **nombre y apellido** de los clientes, el **total facturado** y que porcentaje del total facturado gastaron.

| Nrocli | NyApe | Facturado | Porc_del_total_facturado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 179 | Natalia Lopéz | 781.00 | 15.81611988659376265700 |
| 109 | Pedro Garcia | 641.00 | 12.98096395301741595800 |
| 160 | Silvana Zabala | 545.00 | 11.03685702713649250700 |

`CLIENTES (Nrocli,     NyApe,       Domicilio, Localidad, Saldocli)`

`FACTURAS (Nrofactura, Cliente,     Fecha)`

`DETALLES (Nrofactura, Renglón,     Articulo,  Cantidad,  Preciouni)`

`ARTICULOS(Nroartic,   Descripción, Rubro,     Stock,     Pto_reposicion, precio)`

`RUBROS   (Cod_rubro,  Descripción)`

Yo quiero hacer una consulta, pero dentro de los parametros de busqueda en el select necesito el resultado de otro select
por ejemplo

```
select sum( d.cantidad ar.precio100/ 'variable en cuestion') * 
from clientes c, 
facturas f, 
detalles d, 
articulos ar
```

eso que dice *variable en cuestion* es un resultado que viene de otro `select`, y no se como incluirlo ahi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas utilizando SQL SERVER u Oracle puedes crear una variable, asignar el valor de dicha variable con una consulta y utilizarla posteriormente en tu siguiente consulta como puedes ver a continuación

```
DECLARE @idPrimerSelect INT
SET @idPrimerSelect = SELECT id FROM Tabla1 WHERE id = 1
SELECT SUM(1/@idPrimerSelect) FROM Tabla2
```

Answer (score 0):

supongo que la pregunta se refiere a esto:

```
select nrocli, 
nyape, 
(select sum(d.preciouni * d.cantidad)
  from facturas f 
  left join detalles d 
  on f.nrofactura = d.nrofactura
  where f.cliente = c.nrocli) total_facturado_por_cliente, 
(select sum(d.preciouni * d.cantidad)
  from facturas f 
  left join detalles d 
  on f.nrofactura = d.nrofactura
  where f.cliente = c.nrocli)
 /
(select sum(d.preciouni * d.cantidad)
  from facturas f 
  left join detalles d 
  on f.nrofactura = d.nrofactura)
 porcentaje_total_facturado_por_cliente
from clientes c
```